# Can the script for median be generalised and put into a function type structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We are using the following script to calculate the median:

```
SELECT 
        [Period] = 'amountPeriodA',             
        [Median] = AVG(x.amountPeriodA)         
INTO    #mediantable
FROM (
        SELECT 
                r.customer,
                r.amountPeriodA,
                [RowASC] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r.amountPeriodA ASC, customer ASC),
                [RowDESC] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r.amountPeriodA DESC, customer DESC)
        FROM #MyExample r 
    ) x
WHERE RowASC IN (RowDESC, ROWDESC-1, ROWDESC+1)
```

Is it possible to generalise a script like this and then code it into the server so that in the future we just have to specify the respective table & columns as parameters and the structure returns the `Median` ?

Comment: How do you plan on reusing the results of the stored procedure? You can't directly put them in a select statement like a user-defined function.

Comment: @JeffO I've not written a UDF before. What every structure I use I need to feed in a whole column of data and then it chucks out the Median and then this number will be used to populate an additional column

Comment: @JeffO so a combination of a UDF and then using `APPLY` will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a `stored procedure`.
It's good when you execute the same query many times with different parameters.

[Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure/)'s a good tutorial about stored procedures on `SQL SERVER`

> A stored procedure is nothing more than prepared SQL code that you save so you can reuse the code over and over again.

Comment: jeez - I use Stored Procedures every day - for approx 4-5hrs!! For some reason I thought I'd need a different structure for this

Comment: So does it work? Did you use a stored procedure. Give us a feedback plz.

Comment: I leave the question open for a couple more days; someone might come back with more detail re. converting the script to a sproc. I'm imagining it will require some dynamic sql.